# Dataframe recursively trace the values until one column is zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Am trying to analyze a legacy menu system and trace the path of the menu options. The menu system has main menu and followed by sub menu. I am trying to get the details from bottom to top.Here is records i extracted from the csv for the 'Pay' screen. 
If we look at it the Pay Menu is called from 3 sub menu. Example Rules and Dispatch. Rules is inturn called from Test Menu

So for the 3 instances of where pay needs to be called. I want to extract as

```
2-10
18-2-10
98-13-4-4
```

How is this possible

```
 MOKEY#MO    MOMNU#MO   MOMNUOPT  MOMNUSEQ  MOOPTDES                        MOOPTCMD               
      111           0       2         20    Dispatch Menu                                          
      131         111      10        120    Pay                             CALL AS650G            
      283           0      98        980    Utilities Menu                                         
      985       3,028       2         30    Rules                           CALL IS216G PARM(' ')  
    1,131         985      10        120    Pay                             CALL AS650G            
    2,391         283      13        300    Key Performance Indicator Menu                         
    2,434       2,445       4        380    Pay                             CALL AS650G            
    2,445       2,391       4         40    Quick Look Weekly Menu                                 
    3,028           0      18        190    Test Menu
```

Below is something i have been doing, and i just have a very basic knowledge on pandas. How can i combine all these statements and get the output

```
import pandas as pd
statDir = 'C:/Users/jerry/Documents/STAT_TABLES/'
csvFile = statDir + 'menu'  + '.csv';
dd = pd.read_csv(csvFile,low_memory=False);
fd1 = dd[dd['MOOPTCMD'].str.contains('AS650G')][['MOKEY#MO','MOMNU#MO','MOMNUOPT']]
print(fd1)
print('==============')
fd2 = dd[dd['MOKEY#MO'].isin(fd1['MOMNU#MO'])][['MOKEY#MO','MOMNU#MO','MOMNUOPT']]
print(fd2)
print('==============')
fd3 = dd[dd['MOKEY#MO'].isin(fd2['MOMNU#MO'])][['MOKEY#MO','MOMNU#MO','MOMNUOPT']]
print(fd3)
print('==============')
fd4 = dd[dd['MOKEY#MO'].isin(fd3['MOMNU#MO'])][['MOKEY#MO','MOMNU#MO','MOMNUOPT']]
print(fd4)
print('==============')
fd5 = dd[dd['MOKEY#MO'].isin(fd4)]
fd5
```